# Указать SAX парсеру на начало документа

Tags: java, android, xml, парсер, sax

В активити запускаю Sax парсер файла, который скачиваю с сервера. Когда выхожу из активити, а затем возвращаюсь обратно, парсер выдает ошибку, так как смотрит на конец файла. Как его повернуть на начало файла?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, участок вашего кода, отвечающего за парсинг файла. Скорее всего, вам нужно пересоздать `InputSource`.

Comment: Обязательно закройте при выходе, позже запустите когда необходимо, уже с новыми условиями, которые уже легко сможете поменять.